# Jasmine test with jquery-mockjax.js stub

Tags: jquery, jasmine, mockjax

I have a basic jQuery ajax call, which I am mocking the response using jquery.mockjax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
    $("button.ajax").on("click", getAjaxResult);
});

function getAjaxResult() {
    $.getJSON("/restful/get", function(response) {
      if ( response.status == "success") {
        $("p.ajax_result").html( response.result );
      } else {
        $("p.ajax_result").html( "There is a problem, cannot ajax get." );
      }
    });
}
```

jquery.mockjax.js stub:

```
$.mockjax({
  url: "/restful/get",
  responseText: {
    status: "success",
    result: "Your ajax was successful."
  }
});
```

At the same time I am trying to write a Jasmine describe block to test when the event is triggered, the ajax as well as the result is successful:

```
it("ajax result should be shown after the button is clicked", function() {
    spyEvent = spyOnEvent("button.ajax", "click");
    $("button.ajax").trigger("click");

    expect("click").toHaveBeenTriggeredOn("button.ajax");
    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();
    getAjaxResult();

    expect($("p.ajax_result")).toHaveText("Your ajax was successful.");
});
```

When I run the test, it always fails. I suspect the expect() was executed before the ajax has finished?

Any idea on how I can refactor it to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You guessed correctly. The mockjax plugin preserves the async nature of the ajax call, and thus your `expect()` fires before the ajax call is complete. You would need to alter the `getAjaxResult()` function to use a callback in order to know when it is complete within your test:

```
function getAjaxResult(cb) {
    $.getJSON("/restful/get", function(response) {
      if ( response.status == "success") {
        $("p.ajax_result").html( response.result );
      } else {
        $("p.ajax_result").html( "There is a problem, cannot ajax get." );
      }

      cb(response);
    });
}
```

Then your test looks like this...

```
it("ajax result should ...", function(done) {  // <<< Note the `done` arg!
    spyEvent = spyOnEvent("button.ajax", "click");
    $("button.ajax").trigger("click");

    expect("click").toHaveBeenTriggeredOn("button.ajax");
    expect(spyEvent).toHaveBeenTriggered();

    getAjaxResult(function() {  // <<< Added the callback here
        expect($("p.ajax_result")).toHaveText("Your ajax was successful.");
        done();  // <<< Don't forget to tell jasmine you're done
    });
});
```